# Extract title from name in c#

Tags: c#, regex

How do I extract title from name as Mr. from Mr.ABC or Dr. from Dr.XYZ or M/S. from M/S. PQR in C#?

Comment: Have you even had a look around o google? For example "get substring from substring in c#"

Comment: Are you sure there will be no `John D. Smith` in your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend regex for a clean way to get the title.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(Mr|Ms|Dr|Sr)\.");
Match match = regex.Match("Mr.ABC");
Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! that would help me to extract title.

Comment: @Vijay no problem, if this works for you please accept as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string on '.' and then take the first value.

`string str = "Mr.ABC";
string title = str.Spilt('.')[0];`

Answer (score 1):

There  is no need to use regex.
Use String Split method:

```
var title = myString.Split('.')[0];
```